# bluebird node promises, cant resolve value

Tags: node.js, express, bluebird

I'm trying to write some promises in my express application using bluebird, but have run into a problem. How do I access the `user` value here - it is not being returned by the `resolve(response)` method.

This is the routes file:

```
router.get('/auth/google/callback', (req, res) => {

    google.getToken(req.query.code)
        .then( () => { google.getUser() })
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user); //undefined - response is NOT defined here
        })
});
```

This is the file to manage authentication from which the methods are exported.

```
module.exports.getToken = (code)=> {
    console.log('step 1');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        oauth2Client.getToken(code, (err, tokens) => {
            if (!err) {
                oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
                resolve();
            }

        });

    });

};

module.exports.getUser = () => {
    console.log('step 2');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{

         plus.people.get({
            userId: 'me',
            auth: oauth2Client
        }, (err, response) => {
            if(!err)
                resolve(response); //response is defined here as the user
            else
                reject(err);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be chaining the `.then` in your routes file off of the wrong method, if you are expecting `google.getUser()` to return the value you want to store in user you should chain the `.then` on the end of that function call.

```
router.get('/auth/google/callback', (req, res) => {

    google.getToken(req.query.code).then( () => { 

        google.getUser().then(user => {
            console.log(user); //undefined - response is NOT defined here
        }); //End getUser().then(..)

    }); //End getToken.then(..)

}); //End router.get(..)
```

Comment: If you want to keep the promise chain at the same level you can return `google.getUser()` in the first `then()`. You would be able to attach the second `then()` directly after the first `then()`

Comment: Julien's suggestion is also completely valid, depends how you want to handle this.

Comment: Ah got it, I'm missing that return statement! Thanks for your help guys.